# UnsatisfiedLinkError while trying to use org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.readNetFromCaffe_0

Tags: java, opencv, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I can compile my code in netbeans 14!

I've checked the opencv 4.7.0 libary's been added, tried putting the opencv-470.jar and .dll in the working directory and have added the models to it too, but it still won't run!

I have also tried a older version of the libary 4.6.0, again no luck!

but when I run the code I get the following error:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'long org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.readNetFromCaffe_0(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'
    at org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.readNetFromCaffe_0(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.readNetFromCaffe(Dnn.java:130)
    at AgeGenderRecognition.AgeGenderRecognition.main(AgeGenderRecognition.java:27)
C:\Users\cam30\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\14\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\cam30\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\14\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

From the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Load networks
        Net ageNet = Dnn.readNetFromCaffe("age_net.caffemodel", "age_deploy.prototxt");
        Net genderNet = Dnn.readNetFromCaffe("gender_net.caffemodel", "gender_deploy.prototxt");
        Net faceNet = Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow("opencv_face_detector_uint8.pb", "opencv_face_detector.pbtxt");
```

Comment: are you familiar with `UnsatisfiedLinkError`?

Comment: Ahh got that one sorted, but I'm still having problems loading the models. ```run:
OpenCV(4.7.0-dev) Error: Unspecified error (FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "age_net.caffemodel") in cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromTextFile, file C:\GHA-OCV-2\_work\ci-gha-workflow\ci-gha-workflow\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp, line 1126
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.7.0-dev) C:\GHA-OCV-2\_work\ci-gha-workflow\ci-gha-workflow\opencv\```